# Why is this Jest/Enzyme setState test failing for my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

#### Expected:

Test runs and state is updated in the Login component, when then enables the Notification component (error message) to be found

#### Results:

Test fails, expected 1, received 0

[image]

Originally before I added redux and the store, thus needing to use the store and provider logic in my test, this [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/)/[Enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) tests were passing.

#### The Login.test (updated current version)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils'
import { createCommonStore } from "../../store";
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'
import { missingLogin } from '../../consts/errors'
// import Login from './Login'
import { LoginContainer } from './Login';
import Notification from '../common/Notification'

const store = createCommonStore();

const user = {
    id: 1,
    role: 'Admin',
    username: 'leongaban'
};
const loginComponent = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <LoginContainer/>
    </Provider>
);
const fakeEvent = { preventDefault: () => '' };

describe('<Login /> component', () => {
    it('should render', () => {
        const tree = toJson(loginComponent);
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('should render the Notification component if state.error is true', () => {
        loginComponent.setState({ error: true });
        expect(loginComponent.find(Notification).length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

#### Login.test (previous passing version, but without the Redux store logic)

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils'
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'
import { missingLogin } from '../../consts/errors'
import Login from './Login'
import Notification from '../common/Notification'

const loginComponent = shallow(<Login />);
const fakeEvent = { preventDefault: () => '' };

describe('<Login /> component', () => {
    it('should render', () => {
        const tree = toJson(loginComponent);
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('should render the Notification component if state.error is true', () => {
        loginComponent.setState({ error: true });
        expect(loginComponent.find(Notification).length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that by mixing the redux store logic into the tests, the `loginComponent` variable no longer represents an instance of `Login`, but an instance of `Provider` wrapping and instance of `Login.`

Thus when you do this

```
loginComponent.setState({ error: true })
```

You're actually calling `setState` on the `Provider` instance.

I would recommend testing the `LoginComponent` you've wrapped with `connect` to produce `LoginContainer` separately from the store state. The Redux GitHub repo has [a great article on testing connected components](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md), which gives a general outline on how to do this.

To summarize what you need to do

1. Export both `LoginComponent` and `LoginContainer` separately
2. Test `LoginComponent` individually from the container, essentially doing what your previous working tests before mixing in redux store state did.
3. Write separate tests for `LoginContainer` where you test the `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and `mergeProps` functionality.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that makes sense, will try get this working.